# How to solve percentage of new

Tags: arithmetic

I am good with all percentage questions except finding the original price of something. If I had a coat that cost $120 after an 8% increase, how do I formulate the original price before the increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the original price be $x$$

so, after 8% increase, the price would be,

$$x+\dfrac{8}{100}\cdot x=120$$

that is , $$1.08x=120$$

$$x=\dfrac{120\cdot 100}{108}$$

we get $x=111$$ approx.

Answer (score 1):

Say the original price was $x$. Then an increase of 8% would change the cost from $x$ to $1.08x$.

So, you must find $x$ so that $1.08x=120$. How could you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the original price. Then $8%$ of $x$ will be $\frac{8}{100}x$.So after the increase price will be $x+\frac{8}{100}x$.As this price is given to be 120, so we have

$$x+\frac{8}{100}x=120$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{108x}{100}=120\Rightarrow x=\frac{120\times 100}{108}$$